# Splitting characters using regex returns an empty value in java

Tags: java, regex, string

Here is my input

....ALPO..LAPOL.STRING

I want to seperate each string when it reaches '.' and store in string array list.

I tried using the below code,

```
  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>    (Arrays.asList(chars.stream().map(String::valueOf)
      .collect(Collectors.joining("")).split("\\.+")));
```

There is a problem with regex **split("\.+"))** .

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

ALPO

LAPOL

STRING

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**

" " - > Blank Space

LAPOL

STRING

It prints the first value of the list as an empty value because there are many '.' present before 'A". How to get rid of this empty value in string array list. Any help would be glad !!

Comment: Do you mean to say you split `....ALPO..LAPOL.STRING` string?

Comment: Yea you can take that input as string or character array list. I have taken it as a character array list and so that code @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty element appears because the delimiters are matched before the first value you need to get.

You need to remove the delimiter symbols from the start of the string first with `.replaceFirst("^\\.+", "")` and then split:

```
String results[] = "....ALPO..LAPOL.STRING".replaceFirst("^\\.+", "").split("\\.+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/UcwEX3)

The `^\\.+` pattern matches the beginning of a string (`^`) and then 1 or more literal dots (`\\.+`). `replaceFirst` is used because only 1 replacement is expected (no need using `replaceAll`).

A bit more details on splitting in Java can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-):

> `public String[] split(String regex)`
>   **Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.**
>   This method works as if by **invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a limit argument of `zero`**. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included** in the resulting array.

However, leading empty elements will be included if found. So, we first need to get rid of those delimiters at the string start.

Comment: It works like charm..!! Could you please explain what the split("\\.+"); regex does ?@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: That is your regex actually. It just matches 1 or more literal dots (periods).

Comment: @Anusha The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) explains it very well: "When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however never produces such empty leading substring."